# Override Horizontal swiping on cells in a vertical collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working on an iOS objective-c project which features a fullscreen vertically scrolling UICollectionView.

I am trying to figure out a way to recognize a horizontal swipe on a CollectionViewCell and call a method when a) a horizontal swipe to the left occurs on a cell and b) a horizontal swipe to the right occurs on a cell

What would be the best way to go about achieving this?